# I can't get my leaflet popup to show the data I want

Tags: django, leaflet, geodjango

I'm trying to display two fields from my model in a popup. (The **name** and **photo**). I can only get one field to display or nothing. I can't figures out how to make it work.

If anyone can point in the right direction, I would be happy.

### Attempt #1

This was my starting point, this will only display `name` or `photo` or whatever I append to `layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.whatever);` but only one.

**`models.py`**

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models


class Marker(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    photo = models.ImageField(blank=True)
    geom = models.PointField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='marker')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**`map/views.py`**

```
from django.core.serializers import serialize
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

from map.models import Marker


def marker_view(request):
    markers_as_geojson = serialize('geojson', Marker.objects.all())
    return HttpResponse(markers_as_geojson, content_type='json')


class MapView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'map/map.html'
```

**`map/urls.py`**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin

from map import views
from map.views import MapView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', MapView.as_view()),
    url(r'^map.data/', views.marker_view, name='markers'),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**`map/map.html`**

```
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load leaflet_tags %}
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Map</title>
    {% leaflet_js %}
    {% leaflet_css %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/map.css' %}">
    <script src="{% static 'js/leaflet.ajax.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/leaflet-hash.js' %}"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function map_init_basic(map, options) {
        var geojsonPointLayer = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("{% url 'markers' %}", {
            onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
                layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.name);
            }
        });
        var hash = new L.Hash(map);
        geojsonPointLayer.addTo(map);
    }
</script>
{% leaflet_map "myMap" callback="window.map_init_basic" %}
</body>
</html>
```

Here is an example of `map.data` serialized json getting passed in from the **`map/views.py`**

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "crs": {
    "type": "name",
    "properties": {
      "name": "EPSG:4326"
    }
  },
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          9.294433592456013,
          56.05363501384915
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": "Denmark",
        "photo": "img_q2IgofC.jpg",
        "pk": "1"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

---

### Attempt #2

**I did tried to modify the model to pass in a popupContent using property descriptor, as I understand this I could overwrite, send extra or modify what is being send using @property. I realize I might have completely missed the mark on this, because nothing is added to the serialized data. And the popup doesn't work when clicked**

**`map/models.py`**

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models


class Marker(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    photo = models.ImageField(blank=True)
    geom = models.PointField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='marker')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    @property
    def popupContent(self):
        return '<img src="{}" /><p><{}</p>'.format(self.photo.url, self.name)
```

**`map/map.html`**

```
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load leaflet_tags %}
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Map</title>
    {% leaflet_js %}
    {% leaflet_css %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/map.css' %}">
    <script src="{% static 'js/leaflet.ajax.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/leaflet-hash.js' %}"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function map_init_basic(map, options) {
        var geojsonPointLayer = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("{% url 'markers' %}", {
            onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
                if (feature.properties && feature.properties.popupContent) {
                    layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.popupContent);
                }
            }
        });
        var hash = new L.Hash(map);
        geojsonPointLayer.addTo(map);
    }
</script>
{% leaflet_map "myMap" callback="window.map_init_basic" %}
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Attempt #1` in `map/map.html` try replacing this line:

```
layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.name);
```

with this:

```
layer.bindPopup('<img src="'+feature.properties.photo+'" /><p>'+feature.properties.name+'</p>');
```

You essentially need to build the HTML for the popup in the JavaScript, not in Python.

Comment: Thanks @themanatuf. Very simple. I did try some JS and concatenation. But it was way off. I guess I better start learning JavaScript, I suck so bad at it.